# Using DB2, how do you select rows with MAX for one column and then select rows with MAX on the resulting subset for another column on the same table?

Tags: sql, db2

For example this is the data set on the table PEOPLE:

```
Name     Due_Date     Seq_Num
Peter    2020-03-01   001
Peter    2020-03-01   002
Peter    2020-03-02   001
Paul     2020-03-03   001
Paul     2020-03-03   002
Paul     2020-03-04   001
Paul     2020-03-04   002
Mary     2020-03-05   001
Mary     2020-03-05   002
```

If I do SELECT NAME, MAX(DUE_DATE), MAX(SEQ_NUM) FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY NAME it will return the ff:

```
Name     Due_Date     Seq_Num
Peter    2020-03-02   002
Paul     2020-03-04   002
Mary     2020-03-05   002
```

But what I want is:

```
Name     Due_Date     Seq_Num
Peter    2020-03-02   001
Paul     2020-03-04   002
Mary     2020-03-05   002
```

Because I want the MAX() Seq_Num for the MAX() Due_Date and for Peter, on his MAX() Due_Date, there is no Seq_Num 002, so the value output should be 001. How do I select this via SQL (DB2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH PEOPLE (Name, Due_Date, Seq_Num) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('Peter', '2020-03-01', '001')
, ('Peter', '2020-03-01', '002')
, ('Peter', '2020-03-02', '001')
, ('Paul ', '2020-03-03', '001')
, ('Paul ', '2020-03-03', '002')
, ('Paul ', '2020-03-04', '001')
, ('Paul ', '2020-03-04', '002')
, ('Mary ', '2020-03-05', '001')
, ('Mary ', '2020-03-05', '002')
)
*/
SELECT Name, Due_Date, Seq_Num 
FROM
(
SELECT Name, Due_Date, Seq_Num, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY Due_Date DESC, Seq_Num DESC) MX_
FROM PEOPLE
)
WHERE MX_ = 1;
```